# Sort list of key value pairs in python dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, adjacency-list

How can I sort an adjacency list in python that is store as a dictionary?

```
Adjacency List:
0: [(7, 0.16), (4, 0.38), (2, 0.26), (6, 0.58)]
1: [(5, 0.32), (7, 0.19), (2, 0.36), (3, 0.29)]
2: [(3, 0.17), (0, 0.26), (1, 0.36), (7, 0.34), (6, 0.4)]
3: [(2, 0.17), (1, 0.29), (6, 0.52)]
4: [(5, 0.35), (7, 0.37), (0, 0.38), (6, 0.93)]
5: [(4, 0.35), (7, 0.28), (1, 0.32)]
6: [(2, 0.4), (3, 0.52), (0, 0.58), (4, 0.93)]
7: [(4, 0.37), (5, 0.28), (0, 0.16), (1, 0.19), (2, 0.34)]
```

I would like each row to be sorted by the floating point number.

This is how the values were added but with a loop and reading from stdin rather than manually:

```
adjList = defaultdict(list)
adjList[0].append((7, 0.16))
```

I understand I have to use sorted() and I've tried stuff like this:

```
sorted(adjList)
```

or

```
for i in adjList:
sorted(adjList[i])
```

or

```
value for (key, value) in sorted(adjList[0])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) returns a new sorted list given an iterable. If you want to sort in-place, use [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=sort#list.sort):

```
from operator import itemgetter
for k in adjList:
    adjList[k].sort(key=itemgetter(1))
```

The `key=itemgetter(1)` makes sure it is sorted on the second element of the tuple, alternatively you could also write `key=lambda x: x[1]`.

If you want to sort in decreasing order instead, use `key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

```
my_dict = {
    0: [(7, 0.16), (4, 0.38), (2, 0.26), (6, 0.58)],
    1: [(5, 0.32), (7, 0.19), (2, 0.36), (3, 0.29)],
    2: [(3, 0.17), (0, 0.26), (1, 0.36), (7, 0.34), (6, 0.4)],
    3: [(2, 0.17), (1, 0.29), (6, 0.52)],
    4: [(5, 0.35), (7, 0.37), (0, 0.38), (6, 0.93)],
    5: [(4, 0.35), (7, 0.28), (1, 0.32)],
    6: [(2, 0.4), (3, 0.52), (0, 0.58), (4, 0.93)],
    7: [(4, 0.37), (5, 0.28), (0, 0.16), (1, 0.19), (2, 0.34)]
}

out = {k: sorted(v, key=lambda x: x[1]) for k, v in my_dict.iteritems()}
print out
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=sort#list.sort) with a key function. Since you want to sort by the second element of each tuple, the key function must select the second item (`t[1]` below) from each tuple, `t`:

```
for key in adjList:
    d[key].sort(key=lambda t: t[1])
```

`list.sort()` will sort the list in place no rebinding of variables is required.